# Добавить разблокировку отпечатком пальца в приложение Telegram

Tags: python, telegram

Возможно ли запросить на экране ввода кода блокировки Telegram Windows, отпечаток пальца, который встроен в ноутбук? Например, у меня Telegram заблокирован кодом, при развертывания приложения Telegram одновременно запрашивает код и активирует сканер отпечатка пальца. Если ты к нему прикасаешься, то Telegram соответственно разблокируется. Сразу скажу, ничего не пробовал, так как не смог найти на русскоязычных форумах взаимодействие со сканером.

Comment: А у поддержки телеграмма не спрашивали?

Comment: @gil9red, если честно даже не додумался.